# primefaces fileDownload XML5619: Incorrect document syntax. Line: 1, Column 1

Tags: file, primefaces, download, jsf-2.2

I am using PF 5.3.5 and Mojarra 2.2.8 and I am implementing a log file download but nothing happens.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.SUPPORT_DOWNLOAD_APP_PROPS}" title="#{msg.SUPPORT_DOWNLOAD_APP_PROPS} (d)" accesskey="d">
   <p:fileDownload value="#{supportController.downloadProperties}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

and backend

```
public StreamedContent getDownloadProperties() {

        StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            propConf.save(bos);

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            if (is != null)
                file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is);
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.log(Level.DEBUG, "Download Prop: " + bos.toString());
            }
            return file;

        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            LOG.error("Could not save the collected properties", e);

        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(bos);
        }

        return file;
    }
```

I see no downloaded file only this error below inside of IE11 console, in Mozilla console is this error **syntax error app-info.xhtml:1:1** and no back-end errors.

**XML5619: Incorrect document syntax. Line: 1, Column 1**
Any help, comments are really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting up the attribute of p:commandButton  to `ajax="false"`.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.SUPPORT_DOWNLOAD_APP_PROPS}" title="#{msg.SUPPORT_DOWNLOAD_APP_PROPS} (d)" accesskey="d" ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{supportController.downloadProperties}" />
</p:commandButton>
```